# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result() with click counter function

Tags: php, mysql

here is my function to count clicks from ips,

```
function get_client_ip() {
$ipaddress = '';
if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
   $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
else
    $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
return $ipaddress;
```

}

and the click counter

```
function update_visitas($id,$ip) {
global $dbc;
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ipclicks WHERE ip = "  . ip2long($ip) . " and ads = " . $id;

$res=mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);

if (mysqli_result($res, 0)==0){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ipclicks VALUES (" . ip2long($ip) . "," . $id . ")";
        #echo $sql;
        $res=mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);           

        $sql = "UPDATE ads SET vistas = vistas +1 WHERE id_ad = " . $id;
        #echo $sql;
        $res=mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);       
}
```

}

how can i replace mysqli_result in this function to avoid this error?
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result()

Comment: mysqli_result is not a function, it is a class.  $res is a mysqli_result object.  See the return values for http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not an exact 1:1 match between the deprecated mysql functions and the mysqli functions. You have to fetch a row as an array, and then inspect an element of it.

Example:

```
$res = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($res);
if ($row[0]==0){
    . . .
```